# Finding out where the bandwidth is being used

Tags: bandwidth, iptables

Recently on some of our sites the bandwidth being used has risen tenfold and we want to know what is using it. All we have so far is the MRTG graphs that just say 'you used X much at this time'.

I would like to break down this information by service (ftp, http etc), direction (inbound or outbound), source and destination address and when.

To this end I have started logging all the packets through iptables. This seems to give me what I want at a very detailed level. Is there some tool that will take that log file and condense the information in some way.

Ideally it would provide information like:

```
1.1.1.1 send 123 bytes to 2.2.2.2 via http at 2011-02-24T10:03:17
```

Any ideas as to how I might achieve this or at least some pointers to making sense of the iptables log format.

Answer (score 0):

A good tool for network analysis is Ethereal
Not sure if it will give you what you want exactly, but it will tell you what's going on with your network.

http://www.ethereal.com/

Comment: I have considered this, including tcpdump, but this is just another way of collecting data. I have since found that the logging rules that I added to iptables were inserted at the wrong point and the output of the logging process is now usable. With logging on and logrotate I can go back to the problem and see what was happening after it goes wrong rather than sitting there all day waiting for something to happen.